Draw ggplot2 barplot with round corners
I used the "ggchicklet" package to produce rounded stacked bar plots in R. However, this package is no longer available.
On R News page is written "Use ggforce to replace ggchicklet as ggchicklet is not available at CRAN <2024-03-08, Fri>". However, I was unable to generate a desired stacked bar plot. On this page is an example of ggchicklet usage.
Now is available the package ggrounded but only for rounding the top corners.
Are there any suggestions for an alternative for bars with top and base corners rounded? Thanks.

The ggchicklet was never available on CRAN. There are instructions on how to install it from the github repo: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggchicklet. use install.packages("ggchicklet", repos = "https://cinc.rud.is") or remotes::install_github("hrbrmstr/ggchicklet")

When trying github, I receive the message package ‘ggchicklet’ is not available for this version of R

What version of R are you using? You mean you ran the remotes::install_github command? What the the only output you received? I don't usually see that message with the remotes command

I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 and R version 4.4.1. I got the message above em running install.packages command. I run the remotes command but ggchicklet was not listed in the update list. Only now all chose option 1 (update All) and ggchicklet was installed. Thanks, problem solved.

I mean "Only now I chose option 1 (update All) and ggchicklet was installed."

As suggested in the referenced link here is an option to draw rounded bars using ggforce::geom_shape which however requires to transform the data for which I use dplyr::reframe, i.e. similar to the input for a geom_polygon geom_shape requires to specify the coordinates for the four corners of the bar:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), outcome = c(2.3, 1.9, 3.2))

width <- .9

df <- df |>
  mutate(trt = factor(trt)) |>
  dplyr::reframe(
    data.frame(
      x = rep(as.numeric(trt) + width / 2 * c(-1, 1), each = 2),
      outcome = c(c(0, outcome), rev(c(0, outcome)))
    ),
    .by = trt
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x, outcome, fill = trt)) +
  geom_shape(radius = .05)


